# Saber si una imagen es toda negra con any()

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando con imágenes y querría saber si toda ella es negra. Si no voy errado cuando una imagen es toda negra tenemos una matriz de todo 0.

Por lo tanto yo he pensado que si le aplico la función `any()`, si me devuelve un `False` es que es negra, si me devuelve `True` es que al menos hay un pixel que no es negro.

```
print(img.any())
```

¿Es esto correcto? Es que estoy haciendo eso, pero no se si realmente lo que me devuelve es lo que quiero.

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar [`np.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) que retorna `True` o `False` en caso que alguno de los elementos del `array` sea Verdadero. Un pixel negro absoluto sabemos que se representa con `0` (que se coerciona a `False`) en cada canal, por lo que negando esto deberíamos identificar una imagen completamente negra.

```
is_black = not np.any(img)
```

O bien podríamos usar [`count_nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero) de la siguiente forma:

```
is_black = (np.count_nonzero(img) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código detecta el negro de una imagen, considerando un rango entre "negro claro" y "negro oscuro", expresados en arreglos de numpy:

> negro_oscuro = np.array([0, 0, 0])
>
> negro_claro = np.array([20, 20,20])

Puedes ajustar la sensibilidad al color buscado modificando los arreglos anteriores.
Luego, el valor de la variable **mascara**, será una versión en blanco y negro de la imagen, en donde todo lo que corresponda al color buscado, será blanco, por eso el **if** evalúa lo siguiente:

> if mascara.min() == 255:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
imagen = cv2.imread("imagen.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

negro_oscuro = np.array([0, 0, 0])
negro_claro = np.array([20, 20, 20])

mascara = cv2.inRange(hsv, negro_oscuro, negro_claro)
if mascara.min() == 255:
    print("Totalmente negra.")
else:
    print("Suerte la próxima vez.")
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero no quiero buscar rangos de negros, precisamente lo que ha generado esa imagen negra viene de un código similar al tuyo. Lo que me interesa es saber si con `.any()` me devuelve un booleano de si es `True` o `False`.

Comment: Hola Nea. Omití a propósito lo del **.any**, porque vi que no había más código de referencia. ¿Podrías indicar con qué módulo estás trabajando, y si es posible, mostrar un trozo de código funcional, para poder investigar con más material?